# Determine Big-O of heap creation function

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, big-o, heap

What is the Big-O notation of this heapify method? I was expecting O(log n) but it does not add up? How do I make it O(log n)?

Assuming we have this:

```
int arr[] = {1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 9, 4, 6};
int n = arr.length;
int i = 0; // Start position



void heapify(int arr[], int n, int i) {
        int largest = i;
        int left = 2 * i + 1;
        int right = 2 * i + 2;

        if(left < n && arr[left] > arr[largest]) {
            largest = left;
        }

        if(right < n && arr[right] > arr[largest]) {
            largest = right;
        }

        if(largest != i) {
            int swap = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[largest];
            arr[largest] = swap;

            heapify(arr, n, largest);
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Don't write, never present code not [(doc-)commented](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide).

Comment: (A procedure like this conventionally is called *sift*, with the possible postfix of *down* more often than *up*. *heapify* is used for coercing all of an array with order unknown to comply with the heap condition.)

Answer (score 1):

This is already O(log n).  The value of `i` at least doubles with every recursive call, and when `i >= n` it stops, and after the first call `i` is at least one, so there can be at most O(log n) recursive calls.